# Cypress Radio Button Assertion

Tags: javascript, radio-button, cypress

I am new to Cypress and JavaScript and want to know how to assert that a radio button is selected.

I have `cy.get('[type="radio"]').should('be.checked')` but that seems to validate all of the radio buttons on the screen.

I want to assert that a specific radio button is selected.

Comment: What do you know about the radio? className, ID?

Answer (score 2):

Which commands you use depends on the HTML you are working with,

At minimum, you can expect the radios to be labelled for the user.

**Labels on the left, use `.next()`**

```
html: `
    <label>One</label>
    <input type="radio" checked>

    <label>Two</label>
    <input type="radio" >
`,
test: `

cy.contains('label', 'One')
  .next()                                // select the next element
  .should('have.attr', 'type', 'radio')  // confirm it's type radio (optional)
  .should('be.checked')

`
```

**Labels on the right, use `.prev()`**

```
html: `
    <input type="radio" checked>
    <label>One</label>

    <input type="radio" >
    <label>Two</label>
`,
test: `

cy.contains('label', 'One')
  .prev()                                // select the previous element
  .should('have.attr', 'type', 'radio')  // confirm it's type radio (optional)
  .should('be.checked')

`
```

**Labels have "for" attribute, use `.get('input#my-id')`**

```
html: `
    <input type="radio" id="one" checked>     
    <label for="one">One</label>

    <input type="radio" id="two" >
    <label for="two">Two</label>
`,
test: `

cy.get('input#one')                      // select by id used to associate the label
  .should('be.checked')

`
```

**Labels are grouped by "name", use `.get('input[value="my-value"]')`**

```
html: `
    <input type="radio" name="my-radios" value="one" checked>
    <label for="one">One</label>

    <input type="radio" name="my-radios" value="two" >
    <label for="two">Two</label>
`,
test: `

cy.get('input[value="one"]')           // select by group value attribute
  .should('be.checked')

`
```